# Is there a UI library for angularjs for use in a phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, angularjs

I am looking at angularjs as a choice for developing phonegap apps in. How do you create the mobile experience with things like slides, flips, title bars with history, lists etc?

I have been looking at morpheus (https://github.com/ded/morpheus

Comment: Use Ionic framwork or TopCoat UI. These works well with angularJS without any conflict unlike most other UIs. If you use framworks based on jQuery such as jqm, angularJS will be very much limited.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Lungo.JS](http://lungo.tapquo.com) + Angular + a piece of bridging code, imaginatively called, the Lungo-Angular-Bridge - https://github.com/centralway/lungo-angular-bridge (disclaimer, I wrote it :D).

We found Lungo.JS to be highly performant on mobile devices, the comment from one of our JS guys was "it's even better than native!" - your only issue there will be the fact that Lungo is licensed under GPL3, though a commercial licence is available (the price of which isn't extortionate).

You can find the 'kitchen sink' demo of Lungo here: lungo.tapquo.com/example/index.html they don't really support deployment as an app (i.e. Phonegap), however that's something else we're targetting.

Our bridging code is still pretty alpha, though we're in the process of developing two apps based on it so we're finding and fixing issues pretty quickly. In fact, I'd best go fix one right now.

**Edit**

As of, well, at least a year or so now, use the lovely [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com) for  hybrid apps that you deploy direct into the phone (as opposed to mobile webapps).

The framework I originally suggested is no longer being worked upon. The UI framework it was based upon, Lungo.JS, *is* still being developed.

Comment: i have been looking this bridging code and I like what I see so far, my only concern is that the documentation on LungoJS is great for getting started but not so great when you want to dig deeper to integrate it with other technologies... Also there seems to be little to no community support. The forums are not too active and the developers seem to respond to issues sporatically IMHO

Comment: Agreed, the deeper you go the more on your own you are. As a company we're digging deeper and deeper and pushing the boundaries. Support is indeed a little sparse but we're not finding any (huge) problems - and if we do, we'll contribute back to improve the software *and* the community. We're betting big on Lungo, hence our bridging code.

Comment: I am using you bridge code and your support is awesome. I will share my experiences with you and let you know how it goes and hopefully I can give something back through my experiences

Comment: Any updates? Curious to hear more about this...

Comment: **NOTE** lungo-angular-bridge is not longer under maintanance, @otupman is recommending ionic now. ;)

Comment: Yup, as Max says in the next answer (which I just upvoted) Ionic Framework is exactly where you should go *especially* if you're looking to work with AngularJS.

Answer (score 9):

Just throwing in a plug for our own [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) which is specifically built with AngularJS in mind. Also, it's MIT licensed so you can use it for free in both open source and commercial projects.

We've tried to offer a UI library that lets you create native-style interfaces. With modern phones it's amazing what you can do with HTML5, and we are definitely aggressive about offering animations and gestures.

Comment: Upvoting as the accepted answer is in the maintenance mode.

Comment: Throwing my weight behind this one as one can't delete an accepted answer :(

Answer (score 3):

I made [angular-mobile-nav](http://github.com/ajoslin/angular-mobile-nav) specifically for phonegap apps :-).

Comment: any apps (iphone) in the store using it?

Comment: Not yet as far as I know. I created it for an app I'm working on that will be released soon - I'll add that one to the README once it's up.

Some people are using it for other projects, though - maybe they have something released.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular with jQuery Mobile thanks to https://github.com/tigbro/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter

Comment: I have issues with jquerymobile as it isn't very performant on certain handsets. So i am looking at alternatives and came across angularjs, but am curious to know how people deal with creating the mobile experience.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery Mobile is definitely a bit sluggish. Maybe consider a good responsive UI framework like bootstrap. Look at the angular-strap project.

Comment: I have had significant problems with that project and hence I ended up here!

Comment: I've been using jQueryMobile, mostly because it seemed to offer the most tested, cross-browser mobile-optimized UI widgets around.  Performance has been fine.  Looking back, I still think it was the right choice.  We needed a large catalog of UI mobile widgets, but an MV* architecture was not as important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intel App Framework UI and AngularJS to get things like slides, flips, title bars with history, etc.

I haven't tried it but it looks like [this](https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=4746&p=18601&hilit=angular#p17496) here is a good starting point.