# Choosing library for UI widgets for mobile app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, zepto

I've been developing a mobile app with AngularJS and zeptoJS but the combination of those two is not providing any UI widgets

I've seen this topic: [Is there a UI library for angularjs for use in a phonegap app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045533/is-there-a-ui-library-for-angularjs-for-use-in-a-phonegap-app)

but I'm looking for more answers ( really, LungoJS is the only answer? and I'm not going to use jQueryMobile. ). Are there any other light libraries ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[IonicFramework](http://ionicframework.com/) is a framework designed for exactly this purpose. Its fairly modern though. As such it doesn't have much in the way of backwards compatibility.

- [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org) (currently for 1.x only)

  - [Material Design components for Angular 2](https://material.angular.io/)
- [OnsenUI](http://onsenui.io/) - "The answer to PhoneGap UI Developement"
- [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)
- [NativeScript Angular](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-0)

Comment: aaand could you tell me what is the difference between ionic and bootstrap twitter?

Comment: @Mati The primary difference is that ionic is optimized for AngularJS and assumes that you will use that as your application framework.

Comment: If anyone interested in a tutorial on how to get started with Phonegap + AngularJS + Ionic: http://www.frontendmatters.com/getting-started-mobile-app-development-phonegap-yeoman-angularjs-ionic/

Answer (score 6):

[Mobile Angular UI](http://mobileangularui.com/) lets you use Bootstrap 3 css stripped out of desktop related media queries and Angular.js to develop mobile apps fast.

Its purpose is to achieve the same of Jquery Mobile but using Bootstrap 3 for the UI and AngularJs in place of Jquery.

It provides also other essential mobile components that are not included in Bootstrap 3 like sidebars, scrollable areas, absolute positioned top and bottom navbars that don't bounce on scroll and more.

Answer (score 3):

I also like TopCoat which is a CSS mobile/desktop framework that works well with Angular. See it in action with angular here: http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/11/sample-mobile-application-with-angularjs/ and the library at http://www.topcoat.io

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here where I resumed other options for UI frameworks as well as Pros and Cons.
Including kendo UI, phone.js, chocolate chip, steroids.

[Custom CSS for Mobile development using Phonegap/Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158108/custom-css-for-mobile-development-using-phonegap-cordova/20167603#20167603)

Top coat and bootstrap also nice ones as already mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe reconsider jQueryMobile.

Quite a few months ago we started a new project and considered all of the options listed above for a client side framework. We were looking for a large set of mobile-optimized UI widgets. A widget catalog was more important to us than whether the framework provided an MV* architecture, so tools like AngularJS, MeteorJS and EmberJS were secondary. We found jQueryMobile as the best option for us. Bootstrap, Ionic, Kendo, Sensa, etc. didn't seem to have as many and varied out-of-the-box widgets specifically for mobile. The space of mobile tools is in transition, but so far I think we made the best decision for our use case.